# Row in MySQL Database causing error in Vaadin

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, vaadin

I've started to test using Vaadin for consideration as a replacement technology for an existing system. As a test, I've tried connecting to the existing database, and for some of the tables it works without issue. The problem is that for some of the other tables, in this case the most important one, it chokes on certain rows of the database. The issue is, how do I either a) identify the problem row based on the error message given or b) find a way to make the system identify the problem row and move over it without completely crashing in response?

This is the error message here (note that CPI Entry Not Found is actually a value within the table and so not the cause of the error):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Value '5952182111120050000000û0100100000ûRoad - Base
Brush RoadDouglas Line - Hubbard Line101.000ûû002012-05-21 22:16:59
2012-05-21support300ûû3688.47014531.53
0000-00-0003
2013-12-3117CPI Entry Not Found1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getDateFast(ResultSetRow.java:141)
at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getDateFast(BufferRow.java:707)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2211)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2173)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:5052)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.getPropertyIds(SQLContainer.java:1168)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.<init>(SQLContainer.java:131)
at com.example.testproject.DBTest.init(DBTest.java:36)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:529)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.getBrowserDetailsUI(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2468)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleBrowserDetailsRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2362)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:325)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And here is the relevant code, where the error is thrown on the second line:

```
TableQuery tq = new TableQuery("v3_audits", pool);
SQLContainer container = new SQLContainer(tq);
```

EDIT: Per André's suggestion, I took a look at the database. The indicated row is the first row of the table; deleting it then has the error thrown at the second row. This suggests to me that the database itself is having issues with JDBC as he said--although what that issue might be is hard to guess right now.

Comment: Do you have some more infos about the error ? Stacktrace and something more than a sql exception ? Could it be that your charsets don't match between what vaain is expecting and the jdbc connection-server?

Comment: I've added the full stack trace, but it isn't of much help in this case; the only relevant lines are near the top, which specify that the exception is being thrown by the JDBC connector.

Comment: I think this is a not a vaadin issue, but instead a MySQL + JDBC driver issue. ( Or a corrupt database)
For some reasons the mysql jdbc driver trys to read the column as a date, but apparently the database returns something like a string.
Perhaps exporting the db with a tool using jdbc (Like squirelsql) shows you where the problem is.